# Why do you need the [1] when calling rcloud.notebook.by.name()?

Tags: r, rcloud

In the [RCloud](https://rcloud.social/) function **[rcloud.notebook.by.name()](https://github.com/att/rcloud/blob/320844c098785a1f9820dcd44a3753fafb610fa8/rcloud.support/R/rcloud.support.R)**, why do you need the [1] after the function in [this example](https://rcloud.social/view.html?notebook=6aea3e84416ec9ea8c93f579c360171d):

```
rcloud.execute.asset(name="mtcars.R",
    notebook=rcloud.notebook.by.name(
        user="rclouddocs",
        name="Basic Functionality/Create Reusable Functions/Notebook With R Function in Assets")[1]
)
```

Comment: I'm sure this could be answered with good documentation, but I can't find any for this (short of downloading it myself from GitHub). The `rcloud.notebook.by.name` function must return a vector of items. At which point the `rcloud.execute.asset` function must only require the first item of that vector to run. If you can link in some documentation which explains the functions (or provide some snippets) I might be able to give a more precise answer.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question to include a link to the documentation I found...not sure why vector needed?

Comment: Thanks @LachlanO, indeed [it should be documented](https://github.com/att/rcloud/issues/2569).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function returns more than just the notebook id. It also returns any part of the path which was unconsumed by the query.

So on rcloud.social

```
rcloud.notebook.by.name(
    user="rclouddocs",
    name="Basic Functionality/Create Reusable Functions/Notebook With R Function in Assets")
```

returns

```
     id                                 extra.path
[1,] "6c90abc418dec48ec4e9016ad0187f95" ""
```

But if you add more path to the end:

```
rcloud.notebook.by.name(
    user="rclouddocs",
    name="Basic Functionality/Create Reusable Functions/Notebook With R Function in Assets/blablabla
```

you get

```
     id                                 extra.path  
[1,] "6c90abc418dec48ec4e9016ad0187f95" "/blablabla"
```

This is used internally by `notebook.R`; it's the code that allows fetching assets by user, notebook path, and asset name, for example fetching `mtcars.R` from the same notebook with the following URL:

https://rcloud.social/notebook.R/rclouddocs/Basic%20Functionality/Create%20Reusable%20Functions/Notebook%20With%20R%20Function%20in%20Assets/mtcars.R